# How to change the words in a sentence (string) to Title Case, where the conjunctions in the sentence should stay or change to lower letters

Tags: r, string, stringr

I need to know how to change the words in a sentence (string) to Title Case, where the conjunctions in the sentence have to stay or change to lower letters (all the word).

Something similar to `str_to_title(sentence, locale = "en")`, from the string library, but in which the function recognizes conjunctions (for, and, the, from, etc.).
The most common coordinating conjunctions are: for, and, nor, but, or, yet, and so.

Also, it is important that the word **the** stay as lower case but not when is the first word. The first and last words should always have the first letter in upper case.

For example:

```
sentence = "THE LOVer Tells OF THE rose in HIS HEART"
```

I want the string sentence to change to:

```
"The Lover Tells of the Rose in His Heart"
```

Which is called a [Title Case](https://www.thoughtco.com/title-case-capitalization-1692469#:%7E:text=Title%20case%20is%20one%20of,up%20style%20and%20headline%20style.).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You will have to look for all the stop words and ensure not to change them. Hope the stopeword package would help

Comment: in the meantime`gsub('\\b(\\w)(?=\\w{2})', "\\U\\1", tolower(sentence), perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution?
I figured your question out of programming.

```
sentence <- "THE LOVer Tells OF THE rose in HIS HEART"

require(stringr)

words <- unlist(strsplit(sentence,' ')) %>% tolower()
conjunctions <- c('for', 'and', 'nor', 'but', 'or', 'yet','the','of','in')
for(i in seq_len(length(words))){
  if(i==1 & words[i] %in% conjunctions){
    words[i] <- str_to_title(words[i])
  } else if (!words[i] %in% conjunctions) {
    words[i] <- str_to_title(words[i])
  }
}
words
result <- paste(words, collapse=' ')
result
```

1. Split a sentence to words and and make them `tolower`.
2. Coordinating conjunctions ,except the first word, would be passed and other words would `str_to_title`.
3. `paste` the words into a sentence.

The `result` would be
`[1] "The Lover Tells of the Rose in His Heart"`

Comment: Thank you very much YH Jang !!      
That is awesome. Very clean also.     
I wanted to add a couple of things to the code, let me know what you think (if you want and have time, if not it is ok).         
`characters = c('-', '/', '@', '$', '%', '_', ';', ':','=', ' ')  
words <- tolower(sentence)  
for (j in characters) {    
  words = unlist(strsplit(words, j))
} `    
Divide the sentence in all the words accordingly with the variable 'characters'
  
Also: I change the first if to only this, I think is enough. Where   
`  last_i = length(words)  `
` if( i==1 | i== last_i ) {   `

Comment: ` sentence <- "THE LOVer Tells_OF-THE rose in HIS@HEART and end WITH for"

characters = c('-', '/', '@', '$', '%', '_', ';', ':','=', ' ')

words <- tolower(sentence)  

for (j in characters) {    
  words = unlist(strsplit(words, j))
}
conjunctions <- c('for', 'a', 'from', 'with', 'for', 'the', 'etc' )
last_i = length(words)
for(i in seq_len(length(words))){
  if( i==1 | i== last_i ) {
    words[i] <- str_to_title(words[i])
  } else if (!words[i] %in% conjunctions) {
    words[i] <- str_to_title(words[i])
  }
}
words
result <- paste(words, collapse=' ')
result
 `

Answer (score 0):

Load the package using`library(tools)`, use the toTitleCase function to convert your string `toTitleCase(sentence)` and it's done! Just be mindful that this function only works for English, not any other languages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35823673)